# how to check status inside NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, nsmutablearray

I have 3 `NSMutableArray`. I want compare two `NSMutableArray` of three and find different index and store in another`NSMutableArray` . I want print this sentence when dont save in third `NSmutableArray`.

this is my code but its not working:

```
            NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            jsonArray = [dic objectForKey:@"Modified"];
            NSMutableArray *sqliteArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [sqliteArray addObjectsFromArray:ModiArray];
            differentValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //guys jsonArray and SqliteArray not different index
        if ([jsonArray count] == [sqliteArray count])
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < [sqliteArray count]; i++)
                {
                    if (![jsonArray[i] isEqual:sqliteArray[i]])
                    {
                        [differentValue addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i+1]];
                    }
                }
//My problem here!!! when I NSLog differentValue show me empty but when I write this code dont work
                if (differentValue == NULL)
                {
                    NSLog(@"this array is null");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between a null* array and an empty array, just like there's a difference between a blank shopping list and not having a piece of paper. If you want to test if the array is empty, the easiest way is to say `if(differentValue.count == 0)`.

(mayuur is also correct that you can replace the whole loop with a call to `-containsObject:`, but there's nothing wrong with your code; it's just not using the frameworks as well as it could.)

* Actually, `nil` is slightly preferred for objects, because it's declared as an `id`, but it doesn't matter in this code.

Comment: count is not a property... you should write it [differentValue count] ;)

Comment: @Bastian That's a matter of style. Since Foundation doesn't use properties at all, I prefer to call "property-like" Foundation methods using property syntax; it still works fine and my code is a little bit easier on the eyes.

Comment: Yeah .. I just hope people are not starting to do stuff like `NSArray.alloc.init` because it is easier on the eyes ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty evil...though I must admit, on my grouchier days I've been known to call `copy` with dot syntax. It's an accessor returning a copy of the object, right? Right?

Comment: @Bastian: No, they write `NSArray.new` :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(![jsonArray containsObject:yourObject])
{
    [differentValue addObject:yourObject];
}
```

Also note that you are doing the below thing, which is leaking memory :

```
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // NOT RELEASED
jsonArray = [dic objectForKey:@"Modified"];
```

instead you could directly assign your array like :

```
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [dic objectForKey:@"Modified"];
```

Comment: my friend my problem this is that differentValue hasn't value and when write this code  if (differentValue == NULL)
                {
                    NSLog(@"this array is null");
                } dont work

Comment: Ohh. Didn't get that earlier from your question